# How to find the basis of a vector space with linear mappings?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Given: Let $V$ be the vector space of all linear mappings $$V: \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$$

What is a basis for $V$?

---

I have thought about a standard basis for *V*, but was unsure how to start/continue with that train of thought.

---

Is it okay to come up with any linear mappings that create and independent set and consider them a basis?

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Each linear map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ can be uniquely represented as a $2$-by-$2$ matrix. Find a basis for the space $\mathbb{R}^{2,2}$ of $2$-by-$2$ matrices, and calculate the corresponding linear maps.

Comment: I think I may have found an answer. Thank you for the hint :)

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent to what Henry W said, but without "matrix terminology":
  A linear transformation from $R^2$ to $R^2$ maps (x, y) to (u, v) with u= ax+ by, v= cx+ dy for real numbers a and b.  Try setting each of a, b, c, d to 1, and the others to 0, in turn.